# How to delete (or de-grid) Tkinter GUI objects stored in a list (Python)

Tags: python, list, object, tkinter, python-3.4

I'm trying to make a program that creates some random amount of GUI objects in Tkinter and stores them in a list. Here (in the code below) I have a for loop that creates a random amount of radio buttons. Each time a radio button object is created it is stored in the list 'GUIobjects'. I do this because otherwise I have no way of accessing the GUI objects later on. What I need to know, now, is how to delete or de-grid the objects.

I have tried self.radioButton.grid_forget(), but this only de-grids the last object created. I'm not sure of there's a way to access each object in the list and use .grid_forget(). If there is, that would be an option.

For now all I need to know is how to delete or de-grid the GUI objects after I create all of them.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.addButton()

    def addButton(self)
        GUIobjects = []

        randInt = random.randint(3, 10)
        self.radVar = IntVar()
        for x in range(2, randInt):
            self.radioButton = Radiobutton(self, text = "Button", variable = self.RadVar, value = x)
            self.radioButton.grid(row = x)

    print(GUIobjects)
    # This is to show that one more object has been created than appears on the screen

    self.radioButton.grid_forget()
    # This de-grid's the last object created, but I need to de-grid all of them

def main():
    a = App()
    a.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As of right now, I try to de-grid the objects right after creating all of them. Once I find out how to de-grid each object, I will somehow need to make a button that de-grid's them (as compared to de-griding them right after they have been created). This button should be able to be put in a method other than 'addButtons' but still in the 'App' class.

Thanks!

Comment: You never add anything into the list `GUIobjects`.   Also, you're going to want to bind the action of removing them to a button, otherwise you'll need to both pack and remove them before calling `mainloop()` in which case you would never see any of it happening.  Finally you can access widgets after making them through methods like `pack_slaves()` on their parent.

Comment: "delete" and "degrid" are two different things. Do you want to delete the objects entirely, or just temporarily remove them from view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store references to each object. Create an empty list and append the reference to the list inside your loop.

```
self.radioButtons = []
for x in range(2, randInt):
        self.radioButtons.append(Radiobutton(self, text = "Button", variable = self.RadVar, value = x))
        self.radioButtons[-1].grid(row = x) # layout the most recent one
```

They won't be garbage collected unless you delete the reference as well.

```
for button in self.radioButtons:
    button.grid_forget()
del self.radioButtons
```